# Definition of the cone generated by a convex set in infinite dimensional space

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

In the case finite-dimensional, for example, $A\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ convex, we know that $\mathrm{cone}(A)$ the cone enerated by $A$ is defined by 
$$\mathrm{cone}(A):=\left\{ \left.\sum_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_{i}x_{i} \:\right|m\leq n+1,\: x_{i}\in A, \: \alpha_{i}\geq 0 \:\:\forall i=1,\ldots,m,\:\: \sum_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_{i}=1\right\}.$$

**The Question:** Let $X$ be a ***infinite-dimensional*** vector space and $A\subseteq X$ convex set. ***Is there a definition of $\mathrm{cone}(A)$ the cone generated by $A$?***

Comment: A first hunch would be to change the upper limit of the sums to $\infty$. Surely you've considered this -- did it output nonsense?

Comment: This is definition of convex hull generated by $A$ not the cone generated by $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is convex, its generated cone is just $$\mathbb{cone}(A)=\{\lambda\cdot a;\ \lambda >0,\ a\in A \}$$ and this definition works both in the finite and infinite dimensional case.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote down a characterization of the convex hull. You don't want $\sum_{i}\alpha_i=1$. If you delete this, and replace "$m\leq n+1$" by 
"$m$ is a positive integer", then you are good.